# automatic horizontally scrolling TextView in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want my message string to get displayed on the screen and get scrolled automatically if my message is big enough to come on the screen.

I have used this in my activity file

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View);

    textview.setTextSize(15);
    textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    textview.setText(message);
```

and this is my xml file

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/View"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

but I am not getting the desired output. I am just getting the message that can come on the screen, rest of the message is not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work provided you only have one scrolling textview, and it's not inside a ListView entry.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
android:singleLine="true" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Comment: try calling setSelected(true) for the TextView in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to set the `TextView` as `focusable`

```
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

This should work

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textScroll"
    android:text= "hello_world test scroll hello scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

`setMovementMethod` is not required in code.

Answer (score 0):

try this, may be it'll help you.

> ```
>   <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/Lyrics_textView2"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:clickable="true"
>             android:onClick="onLyricsClick" 
>             android:smoothScrollbar="true"
>             android:scrollbars="vertical"
>              android:maxLines="6"
>             android:ellipsize="none"
>             android:scrollHorizontally="false"
>             android:singleLine="false"
>             />
> ```